# Automatically synchronizing content between two WordPress installations with different themes and plugins

Tags: database, sync

As the title suggests, I am looking to automatically synchronize content between two WordPress installations.

We are looking to switch themes soon and would like a staging site where we can test new themes and plugins without affecting the main site, so that we can safely develop and show the new site to interested parties before it goes live.

However, we would like the content of the staging site to remain synchronized with the main site. Only one way synchronization is necessary; from main to staging. We do not want changes on staging to affect the main site.

The content to be pulled is: posts, pages, and users.

How can we do this?

Comment: database mirroring won't be an option here as staging will have the wrong URL and any changes would break mirroring or be overwritten. Note though that you can't ask for recommendations here, you need to be able to phrase the question in such a way that you can mark an answer as the accepted _correct_ answer for all people who will ever have this question, not just the most useful answer. You'll also want to be much more specific about synchronisation, e.g. automated vs manual, etc, and if you're looking for a golden canonical solution from WordPress itself none exists